# Unable to find a source for "Cave quid optes"

Tags: idiom, source

After checking several online databases/dictionaries, I have been unable to find a source for what I assumed was a familiar Latin idiom, **Cave quid optes**. Could it be apocryphal? In an essay I'm writing I attribute the phrase very generally to Romans, but I would like to name an author like Horace or Ovid, if possible. Anyone know why I can't find a single entry for this? Is my spelling incorrect?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Since it's a very literal translation of an English idiom I would guess that it's modern.

Comment: The question is, is this even really grammatical? *Cavere* with an indirect question is certainly unusual.

Comment: Cave quid optes is the normal form of the idiom though, isn't it? Is there a more familiar way of expressing "Be careful what you wish for"? Not necessarily more correct but more familiar.